# Disk Cleanup Script is running Ok in terminal but not cleaning when it's scheduled at crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, cron

I have initiated a script which will cleanup disk above 90% automatically.
Logic:

1. 1st df -hT on that particular disk to check usage & keep the output in a file
2. Then find the disk usage with awk command.
3. If the usage is above 90% it will remove the csv files from particular directories.

Code :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Clean for servers data disk.
# 2021.10.23

# Main

#> "$SCRIPT_SUM"
df -hT /data* > "$SCRIPT_SUM"
disk_space=$(grep 'data1' SCRIPT_SUM.txt | awk -F "  " '{print $5}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
disk_space=${disk_space%\%}

if [[ $disk_space -gt 90 ]]; then
        /home/dir_1/dir_2/path.sh
#       . path.sh
#       cd c++
#       /adapter_script.sh 0 >> "$SCRIPT_LOG" 
#Stop the adapter 
        /home/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/adapter_script.sh 2 >> "$SCRIPT_LOG"
        sleep 30
        rm /data1/dir_11/*.csv
        rm /data1/dir_12/*.csv
        rm /data2/dir_11/*.csv
#Start the adapter 
        /home/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/adapter_script.sh 1 >> "$SCRIPT_LOG"
        sleep 30
#Check the adapter status
        /home/dir_1/dir_2/dir_3/adapter_script.sh 0 >> "$SCRIPT_LOG"
        echo 'Disk Clean Up Successful' >> "$SCRIPT_LOG"
#else
#       echo 'Disk Cleanup is not successful' >> "$SCRIPT_LOG"

fi
```

When I run this script from terminal it's running & cleaning files. But when I schedule it in cron it's running but not cleaning files.

I can't find out the cause behind. Can anyone help me in this regards.

```
Cron Job Like
*/10 * * * * /D1/D2/D3/D4/D5/clean.sh
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cron issues usually boils down to PATH not being available via cron, because usually has a limited PATH. This is a FAQ in this forum. Just search for `cron` script or something.

Comment: What will be the possible resolution of it ?

Comment: Short answer is use an absolute PATH for all the executable being used in your script or set the PATH in the cron entry itself.

Comment: I have used absolute path for all the executable being used in script...

Comment: Add this to your crontab entry:  `>/tmp/out1 2>/tmp/out2`.  Then you will see what is going on.  If that is not enough, then also add `-x` in your first line to see exactly what bash is doing.  **FYI** $SCRIPT_LOG is not defined **FYI2** df is not called with absolute path, neither are sleep, df, awk, ...